# Hide bootstrap modal when clicked on a div inside the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Why isn't my modal closing? Please help
I am trying to close the modal when a div inside the modal is clicked.
Following is the code. When i click it nothing happens.

```
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Language</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit_form">Submit</button>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <script>                    
                $('.modal-footer').click(function() {
                   $('.modal').modal('hide');

                });
                $('.test').click(function() {
                   $('.modal').modal('hide');

                });   
                </script>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the code above generated with AJAX as the code works fine? Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/gV6y8/48/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, best to include your jquery functions inside $(function(){});

Have you included the Bootstrap JS file?

What div are you aiming to click on to close your modal? Your code is correct but you've used a ".test" selector without a div that uses the test class.

Regardless, your code should work.

```
            $(function(){                    
                $('.modal-footer').click(function() {
                   $('.modal').modal('hide');

                });
                $('.test').click(function() {
                   $('.modal').modal('hide');

                });   
            });
```

Fiddle with a ".test" div added.
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8967/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the best practices like using function() since I am newbie. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
data-dismiss="modal"
```

into `<div class="modal-footer">`

You can see [my code example](http://jsbin.com/nesemu/3/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks. I had to add data-dismiss="modal" because the webpage was still dark even when the modal was closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>                    
            $('.modal-footer').click(function() {
               $('#myModal').modal('hide');

            });
            $('.test').click(function() {
               $('#myModal').modal('hide');

            });   
 </script>
```